# didRangeBeacons delegate call returning just one beacon at a time

Tags: ios, ios8, ibeacon

I am working on a app related to iBeacons. There are 2 beacons, each beacon having the same UUID but different major/minor values. But the 
`- locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:` delegate callback "beacons" array contains only 1 beacon. Alternatively both the devices are ranged but they are not received together.

I have tested my code by setting 2 iPhone's as beacon transmitter and it seems to be working fine.

Can somebody please provide some suggestions?
Could it be some configuration issue in the beacon? or for some reason beacons are not transmitting simultaneously?

Comment: I faced similar problems while using iPhones as beacons, I suggest you to check with actual iBeacons.

Comment: @Ankur The problem is when using the actual beacons. With iPhone's it is working fine.

Comment: Maybe its charge may be finished, if not I advise you to make it to send out 15 advertisements per second.

Comment: check the battery status of your beacon, as @ondermerol said..

Comment: @ondermerol Battery is fully charged. No issues with that.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is related with the beacons? You can test your beacons with the application named Particle Detector.

Comment: @ondermerol The beacons get detected even in my app but the problem is  that they are not detected together.

Comment: Do you know how often the beacons are transmitting?  Perhaps it is infrequent advertising that is causing this problem.  Beacons should transmit at 10Hz for best results with iOS, and at a bare minimum of 1 Hz for normal operations.  If you post the beacon make and model it may reveal this info.

Comment: @davidgyoung Thanks for that info. I will check and update this post if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

This may be normal.  If you are using two different regions, you will always get a different callback to 
`locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion` for each beacon because one of the parameters is the region instance.

Comment: Sorry, but in the question I have clearly mentioned I am using the same UUID for both beacons.

Comment: Sorry to have missed that, I will edit my answer.  Regardless of how many different UUIDs you have on the beacons, are you using two different regions?

Comment: No, Im using a single region. I believe this is some config issue in the beacon itself..?